# Нужна ли запятая после "так" (контекст прилагается)?

Tags: пунктуация

> Но мне кажется, нет ничего приятнее, чем на отдыхе оказаться в стране,
>   густо населённой от природы смешливыми, доброжелательными людьми,
>   которые не понимают, о чём ты говоришь, но рады бы помочь. Жаль, что
>   не можешь объяснить, что конкретно имеешь в виду. Но ведь можно
>   попробовать?! **Так,** всё общение складывается из искренних улыбок и
>   пространных жестов. Дня через два в предвкушении разговора ты уже
>   начинаешь давиться от смеха.

*Пространные жесты*... Помогите найти более точное слово!

Размашистых?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По смыслу больше похоже на "Все пытаются жестикулировать. Именно так общение складывается из улыбок...". Трактовать вариант с запятой сложнее, да и вряд ли автор имел его в виду. Предлагаю править и смотреть на реакцию автора.

"Пространные жесты" я воспринимаю как иносказание в смысле "жесты, не имеющие определённого (точного) значения". Мне это слух не режет. Я не смог найти убедительных примеров употребления, но "пространный смысл" вполне себе встречается.

Answer (score 1):

"Так" мне кажется излишне формальным в тексте непринуждённого стиля, проще "ведь" (без запятой). *Пространный* (размашистый) *жест* вряд ли подходит, возможно, лучше "неясный", "неоднозначный", "интуитивный", "нестандартный" - носители разных языков могут по-разному пользоваться сходными жестами.

Comment: Нет, жесты очень "ясные": кивками, подмигиваньем, подпрыгиванием от нетерпения, не говоря уж о руках...

Comment: Жесты могут быть ясными для жестикулятора и дезориентирующими для реципиента (особеннно про болгар известно) :)

Comment: Не указала: речь о русских и горячих бразильянцев. )))

Comment: Ну пусть жесты будут "эмоциональными" - "пространные" обычно на дверь указывают (хорошо, если "добро пожаловать"). Но речь может идти о предметах, для которых у сурдонеграмотных нет готовых жестов - это не всегда "сколько стоит". "Интуитивный", "нестандартный" - это то, что находчивому русскому в голову на ходу приходит. Помнится, изобретательные китайские мотоциклисты наводящим жестом (нога, закинутая за ногу, на которой стоят, одна рука за спину, вторая над головой) спрашивали: "вам к горе с обезьянами?", а мой коллега водоподобным шипением выведывал, как пройти к водопаду.

Answer (score 1):

1. *Так* с запятой придает тексту ненужную академичность. Я бы убрал запятую, а еще лучше заменить *так* на более разговорное *в итоге* или *в результате*.
2. Неопределенные жесты